# Constraining optaplanner's choices based on the result of different choices - Constraint Propagation / Local Consistency

Tags: optaplanner, constraint-programming

I have an optimization problem that I'm working on in which the optimizer's decision for one variable needs to constrain the available choices for another variable, and I'm wondering about the suitability of different ways of accomplishing this. I'll try to pare it down for demonstration purposes (in kotlin).

```kotlin
@PlanningEntity
class AuctionBid {
  @PlanningId
  lateinit var entity: String
  
  @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["availOptions"])
  var bidNow: Boolean? = null
  @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = ["availOptions"])
  var bidFinal: Boolean? = null
  var forceBid: Boolean? = null

  @ValueRangeProvider(id = "availOptions")
  private fun availOptions(): List<Boolean> {
    return if(this.forceBid != null) {
      listOf(this.forceBid!!)
    } else {
      listOf(true,false)
    }
  }
}
```

In this scenario, we are trying to determine if we should bid on a given entity in a combinatorial auction (multiple entities being bid on in each round), given a hard budget and various cost/benefit tradeoffs. The `bidNow` choice is determined by the prices in the current round of the auction, and the `bidFinal` choice is determined by the anticipated/forecasted final prices in the auction. In order to avoid constantly changing decisions about what to bid on right now (switching bids is penalized in the auction rules), we want to constrain our choices on `bidNow` based on our decision for `bidFinal`, such that if we will want to bid on it at our anticipated future price, we will always choose to bid on it now. A state table seen below:

| bidNow | bidFinal | possible |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Y | Y | Y |
| Y | N | Y |
| N | N | Y |
| N | Y | **N** |

As seen, we already have a method of constraining choices for situations where we know we don't want the product at all, or where we know we want it at any price. This is using the `availOptions` ValueRangeProvider, which only lets the optimizer choose a predetermined option if we know that is our only choice.

However, this constraint is more dynamic, as it results from a separate choice. If we are wanting to bid at the anticipated final price, our only choice for right now is to continue bidding in the current round.

I've thought of a few ways of doing this, as this is a classic [Local Consistency Constraint Propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_consistency) example, but without knowing too much about optaplanner's internals, I don't really know the best way to do this. Some options:

1. Use a separate ValueRangeProvider for `bidNow` than `bidFinal`, and constrain the value range for `bidNow` to `True` if `bidFinal` is true. However, I don't know if optaplanner can even handle a dynamic value range that is determined by another planning variable's value, nor do I know if this is an efficient method.
2. Place a hard constraint (using ConstraintStreams, which is super cool BTW) on `bidNow` to always be `True` if `bidFinal` is `True`. I know this is feasible (it's my current solution), but it seems really slow.
3. Maybe try to use a Shadow variable which I've never used before, although I'm not sure this is a good fit because `bidFinal==True` implies `bidNow==True`, but `bidFinal=False` doesn't necessarily imply anything about `bidNow`.

I know I can always just try all the different options and see, but this problem is already big and unwieldy (the demo code is dramatically simplified), and I really would like some insight into how Optaplanner is working behind the scenes because I really like working with it but come across these this-way-or-that-way scenarios all the time and it's difficult to try them all. Is there any insight into modeling this constraint propagation problem? Or problems like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 1 and 2 should be possible; 2 being the straightforward way.

Another option would be to use [filtered move selection](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/move-and-neighborhood-selection/move-and-neighborhood-selection.html#filteredMoveSelection) to skip the moves that would set `bidFinal` to `Y` if `bidNow` is `false` (and the opposite corner case). The downside of this is that the filter needs to be applied to every move you use, which makes solver configuration verbose. And the moves will still be generated before they are thrown away, so you lose a bit of performance.

However, why not make `bid` an enum with three options: `NOTHING`, `NOW_ONLY`, `BOTH`. That way, you have the benefits of only having one planning variable and completely eliminating the original problem. Of course this is only suitable when the number of options is this low, which it may not be in your actual use case.

This last option is an example of designing your data model in a way to avoid corner cases. If they are impossible because the model precludes them, you do not need to worry about working around them later. This is always your best bet.

Comment: I tried out using #1 and it didn't seem to enforce the constraint...final results had several instances where `bidFinal==True` and `bidNow==False`. My guess is that it has to do with the optimizer only being able to make a single move at a time...and if `bidFinal==False` and `bidNow==False`, but the move selector chooses to switch the `bidFinal` to `True`, then in order to enforce that it would also have to move `bidNow` to `True` simultaneously. Makes sense in retrospect.

Comment: The hard constraint seems to be working for now, and it appears slow but I could also be conflating that slowness with a few other constraints that were added around the same time. I will definitely check out the SelectionFilter. That looks precisely like what I was looking for...a way of ruling out moves before they ever need to be evaluated.

Comment: I do like the idea of using an enum, but my actual problem has three products per entity which can be bid on independently, and there is some combinatorial weirdness in the domain for calculating the value functions that would be significantly more complicated using a ternary logic than a partitioned binary logic.   Nonetheless it's a great idea that I didn't think of, I'll just have to keep it in my back pocket for other problems I'm working on.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing software. I'd love to share how it has helped me and my company sometime if you're ever looking for testimonials.

Comment: We would love that! If you want to write a blog post or some other resource, we'll be happy to link to it from our website. Let us know on the Zulip chat.